# target a custom page using plugin function in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, customization

i created a custom page named `custom_page.php` in wordpress and use this as a **page** template.

i wanted to create my own functions and only target my `custom_page.php`. this function will be installed as a plugin.

what kind of WP HOOKS should i use, for example i have this code below

```
function your_function() {
    if ( is_page_template('custom_page.php') ) {
     echo '<p>This is inserted at the bottom</p>';
     {

}
add_action('wp_footer', 'your_function');
```

i want to only execute this code in my **custom_page.php** footer area.

[EDIT]

Answer (score 0):

You can use these hooks for page templates. 
http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/page_template

Or may be something like this...

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'check_the_template' );
function check_the_template( $template ) {
    if( 'custom_page.php' == basename( $template ) ) {
        // do some things here by calling functions, hooks etc..
    }
    return $template;
}
```

If you want to just echo "Hello World" :

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'check_the_template' );
function check_the_template( $template ) {
    if( 'pagetemplete.php' == basename( $template ) ) {
        add_action( 'the_content', 'echofunction' );
    }
    return $template;
}
function echofunction() {
    echo "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: is there a way i could use this code, and process it after `<HTML>` tag. because when i use this, it ruins my code. for example i wanted to echo `test`. this prints out before my `<HTML>` markup

Comment: Check my edited answer... Not sure if this i the right way.. but you can echo "test" like the above !!